# Including vendor CSS and JS in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In converting a static HTML/CSS site to a wordpress template (for one specific site), how should vendor specific CSS/JS be included in the theme package?

**functions.php method:**

```
    function add_theme_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/asset/vendor/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css', array(), '5.9.0', 'all');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . 
     '/asset/vendor/font-awesome/js/fontawesome.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 5.9.0, true);
     }
     add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

**header.php method:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/asset/vendor/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
```

Some of the wordpress documentation points towards the first (functions.php) method as being preferred method to load resources, but there is no explanation as to why?

Comment: Using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action allows you to control load order of scripts along with dependencies. It also allows you to load scripts into the header or footer. There are lots of resources on the internet about this, including this: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st method is preferred because give you more control about where to include and the resources dependencies, see this example:

```
if(is_page($page_selected)){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'page_scripts');
}
```

As you see you can include the scripts only in the page, or you can target only post, or also you can have different scripts for different user role and so on...

Another thing that supports the use of the 1st method is the separation, separate markup, style, scripts give you a better code to work

Comment: In theory the direct inclusion may have a really imperceptible performance gain because you do directly without server side function execution, but I think that the difference are infinitesimal and the loss in term of maintainability is bigger then gain

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am marking this as the solution, although both will technically work. It would be nice when wordpress changes from one method of doing something to another that some explanation as to why is provided.